# What is the meaning ofDelusions of grandeur. Folks have been institutionalised for less lol

Tags: sentence-meaning

Delusions of grandeur. Folks have been institutionalised for less lol

Comment: The proper response when your question has been closed is to edit it to bring it on topic, not create another account and post it again.

Answer (score 0):

The Phrase Finder, a simple Google search away, gives the following definition of "delusions of grandeur":

> A false and exaggerated belief about one's status or importance.

To be institutionalised (in this context) is to be admitted to a psychiatric hospital.

Comment: Which "the phrase finder" are you referring to? There are several in the search I did. Why not just add the link to it in your answer?

Comment: @ColleenV I think you've answered your second question yourself; there are plenty of sites that would give the answer via a Google search. Linking to a specific one wasn't necessary.

Comment: While that might be true for someone fluent in English, you should keep in mind that sorting through which English sites are credible can be difficult for someone who isn't fluent. Regardless, it was just a suggestion.